# How can I write .htaccess so that it only gives access from the form?

Tags: .htaccess, web-development-server

Here is my code:

```
<files contacts.html>
order allow,deny
deny from all
Allow from access.php
</files>
```

I do not want contacts.html DIRECTLY accessed from the URL. I have a form on the index.html page that has a form with the action access.php. Once it confirms, it redirects it to contacts.html using the header function.

Comment: Well, one possible approach is checking the referrer header. But that's rather weak: first, one may forge it (as any HTTP header can be forged), second, some proxies do not pass it. What I'd suggest is reading the contents of the file within `access.php` file, then echoing it (with correct headers) when form is submitted correctly.

Comment: When you echo the file instead of redirecting, you break the post-redirect-get pattern, what you probably don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `$_SESSION`,

On `access.php`

```
session_start();

// some code here to authenticate

$_SESSION['hasAccess'] = true;

// redirect
```

Change `contacts.html` to `contacts.php` and at the top of this page

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['hasAccess'] !== true){

    header('Location: index.php');
    die;

}

// the rest of your code
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the quick response and elegant response!